# getY() value doesnt change after changing the height of view

Tags: android, android-xml

I have a frame layout that I add different height views to depending on different circumstances.

I would like to know the Y-axis position of the frame layout before and after the view has been added.

So before I add the view I call `getY()` on the frame layout which returns 1891 which is correct, once the new view has been added it still returns 1891 which is wrong, it should be less as the frame layout is higher up the screen.

I've checked the layout inspector for both circumstances and `getY()` gives the correct value so why doesn't my code?

I tried to call `rootLayout.requestLayout()` to redraw the layout after adding the view but that didn't work.

```
    Log.d(TAG, "openActionBar: " + String.valueOf(actionFrameLayout.getY()));

    LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.main_menu_3_item, frameLayout, true);

    questionRoot.requestLayout();

    Log.d(TAG, "openActionBar: " + String.valueOf(actionFrameLayout.getY()));
```

Here is my XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/questionRoot"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="?android:attr/colorBackground"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        tools:context=".QuestionFragments.Question">

        <com.englishquestionstogo.CustomViews.CustomChronometer
            android:id="@+id/timer"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
             />

        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scrollView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/actionFrameLayout"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/questionTitle"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    tools:text="Title" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/questionBody"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/questionTitle"
                    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="32dp"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />

            </RelativeLayout>

        </ScrollView>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/topBorder"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="#D3D3D3"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/frameLayout"
            />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/bottomBorder"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="#D3D3D3"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            />


        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:background="@color/white"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/bottomBorder"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/testButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                />


        </FrameLayout>


        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/actionFrameLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/frameLayout"
            >


        </FrameLayout>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `addOnGlobalLayoutListener`

```
 actionFrameLayout.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(
   new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
      public void onGlobalLayout() {
           //Remove the listener before proceeding
           if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                actionFrameLayout.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
           } else {
                actionFrameLayout.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
           }

           // get the absolute coordinates of a view
           Log.d(TAG, "openActionBar: " + String.valueOf(actionFrameLayout.getY()));

      }
   }
 );
```

Comment: Sorry i forgot to ask, why does it not give me the correct value when i call getY() again?

Comment: yes, because of it not in time, you are calling `getY` too early. The UI has not been sized and laid out on the screen yet.